# What does 1 Corinthian 2:15 mean?

Tags: exegesis, spirituality, 1-corinthians

Is this verse saying that spiritual people are above the judgment of those who are not spiritual?

> Those who are spiritual can evaluate all things, but they themselves cannot be evaluated by others. (1 Corinthians 2:15, NLT)

Comment: Welcome to the site. We are glad you decided to participate. This question is difficult to understand and does not seem fit into one of the [question types that the community finds acceptable.](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/3409/types-of-questions-or-template-questions-that-the-community-generally-finds-ac) If possible, [edit] this question so that it better fits into one of those question types and clears up what exactly you are asking. Thanks. Are you simply asking what the verse is saying?

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be misreading the Scripture, in order to understand a verse of Scripture we must also read and understand the other verses before and after the one we want to understand, and sometimes we even have to read and understand the Chapters before and after the one containing our verse. Sometimes we even have to understand what the entire book is about, this is true of this verse.

The Church at Corinth was begun by Paul on his first tour. It was a wealthy city and a large trading center. The Church itself had been going through some confusion due to the fact that there had been several different theologies taught by a diverse group of people.

Paul's letter was sent to help them to discern the true course of following Christ. In 1st Corinthians 2:1-16. Paul’s subject is, Christ crucified, not in worldly, but in heavenly, wisdom among the perfect.

So let's take a look at some verses and see if we can determine just what Paul is saying.

All Scripture is quoted from the King James translation, unless otherwise noted.

> 1st Corinthians 2:9 through 16 But as it is written, Eye hath not seen, nor ear heard, neither have entered into the heart of man, the things which God hath prepared for them that love him. But **God hath revealed them unto us by his Spirit: for the Spirit searcheth all things, yea, the deep things of God**. For **what man knoweth the things of a man, save the spirit of man which is in him? even so the things of God knoweth no man, but the Spirit of God.** *Now we have received, not the spirit of the world, but the spirit which is of God; that we might know the things that are freely given to us of God.* 
>   But the natural man **Which things also we speak, not in the words which man's wisdom teacheth, but which the Holy Ghost teacheth; comparing spiritual things with spiritual.** receiveth not the things of the Spirit of God: for they are foolishness unto him: neither can he know them, because they are spiritually discerned. But **he that is spiritual judgeth all things, yet he himself is judged of no man.** ***For who hath known the mind of the Lord, that he may instruct him? But we have the mind of Christ.***

Lets break this down and analyze what Paul is telling them.

1. *save the spirit of man which is in him? even so the things of God knoweth no man, but the Spirit of God.*

Here Paul is saying that mere man in his material state can never know the things that are Spiritual.

1. *God hath revealed them unto us by his Spirit: for the Spirit searcheth all things, yea, the deep things of God*.

What Paul is saying here is that the Holy Spirit converses with our spirit, and even makes us aware of the deep things of God.

1. *what man knoweth the things of a man, save the spirit of man which is in him? even so the things of God knoweth no man, but the Spirit of God.*

He goes on to say that man doesn't even know himself, but his Spirit knows, and no man knows the ways of God, only the Holy Spirit knows.

1. *Now we have received, not the spirit of the world, but the spirit which is of God; that we might know the things that are freely given to us of God.*

Now Paul is no longer speaking in general terms he is speaking of himself.

1. *Which things also we speak, not in the words which man's wisdom teacheth, but which the Holy Ghost teacheth; comparing spiritual things with spiritual.*

Here Paul is saying in effect listen to me and not those who are not teaching the same things I teach, because what I'm telling you is what the Holy Spirit has taught me.

1. *But he that is spiritual judgeth all things, yet he himself is judged of no man.*

So now we get to the verse you asked about, and Paul is no longer talking about himself or any other man. He is talking about God! actually it is the third part of the Trinity which is the Holy Ghost.

1. *For who hath known the mind of the Lord, that he may instruct him? But we have the mind of Christ.*

Finally what Paul is saying is has any man understood the mind of God so that he is able to judge The Holy Spirit. And he ends by saying that he has come to see things as Christ does.

Answer (score 0):

Well first lets start with the verse in question

Those who are spiritual
can evaluate all things,
but they themselves
cannot be judged by
others.

1corinthians 2:15

basically since your not asking any specific denomination I will just give a general answer which I believe all denominations could agree upon.

This verse is refering to the Children of God whom having the Ruach haKodesh (The Holy Spirit) could discern, judge, evaluate or understand things better than a carnal  people (non-spiritual). The Holy Spirit is also refered to as the spirit of wisedom, knowledge and understanding so it renders one blessed at discerning (judging) situations.

As for the second portion of this verse
" but they cannot be judged by others" refers to the fact that we cannot be judged because we are justified by Christ ( we are saved, redeemed, our sins are forgiven) and man cannot judge us. Also being that a Child of God has the holy spirit he cannot be judged by ordinary carnal minded men who cannot discern spiritual matters or our spiritual acts and this carnal mindedness blurs there overall judgement of things wheras a Child of God has answers from on high (Heaven) through The Holy Spirit.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this verse saying that spiritual people are above the judgment of
>   those who are not spiritual?

It is saying that in the realm of judgment, those who do not have the spirit of God are unable to judge things that are spiritual. It is not so much a matter of being "above". It is more like saying that those who are not blind can see all things, but they themselves cannot be seen by those who are blind.

This is also described in 1 Corinthians;

1 Corinthians 2:14  But the natural man receiveth not the things of the Spirit of God: for they are foolishness unto him: neither can he know them, because they are spiritually discerned.